# How to search in two sites in Bing

Tags: search, bing

I want to search something in two sites in Bing. Like:

site:xing.com OR site:linkedin.com Jack Hone

But i get null result. In Google it works, but not in Bing.

What is the problem in Bing? Is my syntax false?

Comment: This seems pretty much off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use a search engine instead of directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Just use parentheses for proper grouping:

```
(site:xing.com OR site:linkedin.com) Jack Hone
```

You may want to look at the search syntax:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795667.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This would work :
[(site:xing.com || site:linkedin.com) Jack Hone](http://www.bing.com/search?q=(site%3Axing.com%20%7C%7C%20site%3Alinkedin.com)%20Jack%20Hone&go=Submit&qs=n&pq=(site%3Axing.com%20%7C%7C%20site%3Alinkedin.com)%20jack%20hone&sc=8-46&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=0483b3b1e3a845698c26f8d1b2501d2c&first=31&FORM=PERE2)